# igraph generate adjacency matrix from adjacency list

Tags: r, igraph

I have friendship data in an adjacency list. Every person in the sample (denoted by id) could nominate up to 5 friends (f1-f5). The data frame called "net_test" looks like this:

```
    id   f1   f2   f3   f4   f5
1  1101 1113 1112   NA   NA   NA
2  1102 1111 1113 1103 1105   NA
3  1103 1105 1110   NA   NA   NA
4  1104 1115 1106 1110 1109 1112
5  1105 1103 1109 1116 1101   NA
6  1106 1121 1103 1113   NA   NA
7  1107 1106 1111   NA   NA   NA
8  1108 1104 1109   NA   NA   NA
9  1109 1114 1103 1113 1108 1120
10 1110 1101 1103 1109 1107   NA
```

The first row is the column number. From this data I'd like to generate an adjacency matrix with the ids as row and column names, and entries 1 if two ids have a friendship link. I tried saving it as a graph first, and then generate the adjacency matrix in a second step:

```
require(igraph)
netdat<-graph.adjlist(net_test, mode="out", duplicate=FALSE)
adjmat <- get.adjacency(netdat, type="both")
```

When I apply the graph.adjlist command, the following error occurs:

```
At structure_generators.c:84 : Invalid (negative) vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

Would there be another way to convert the adjacency list into an adjacency matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the commands. The command `get.adjlist` takes as parameter an igraph graph object, and returns a list-type object representation of the graph. You are applying this to a data frame which is not being coerced to an igraph object.

Below is the correct way to construct a igraph graph object using a data frame, and how to get various graph representations of this object.

```
require(reshape2)
net_list <- melt( net_test, id.vars = "id")
net_list <- net_list[ !is.na(net_list$value), c("id", "value") ]
graph_o <- graph.data.frame(net_list) #This is a proper igraph graph object
#got from a data frame directly

list_rep <- get.adjlist(graph_o) #this now returns an adjacency list 
#representation of your graph
matrix_rep <- get.adjacency(graph_o) #this gives you the adjacency
#matrix as a (sparse) matrix with the row and column names as you want.
```

Comment: Although this gives what the OP asks for, it would be nice to note that it  excludes isolated nodes from the graph. net_list[ !is.na(net_list$value), c("id", "value") ] removes all who don't send out any link, and they will only appear in the graph if they receive a link from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is, that `net_test` is no proper adjacency list, because it contains more than just two columns. So the first thing I'd do is bringing it to this form by melting:

```
require(reshape2)
net_list <- melt( net_test, id.vars = "id")
net_list <- net_list[ !is.na(net_list$value), c("id", "value") ]
colnames(net_list) <- c("from", "to")
graph.adjlist(net_list, mode="out", duplicate=FALSE)

# IGRAPH D--- 1121 66 --
```

If you just need the adjacency matrix and without further need for igraph, you could directly `cast` the molten `net_list`

```
acast(net_list, from ~ to, fun.aggregate = length )
```

Comment: Although this gives the adjacency matrix in the form the OP wants, there is a igraph-idiomatic series of steps the OP should be taking. +1 for `acast` though.